# C#: how to get the content of an object as identifier

Tags: c#, xml, class, colors

i ran into a problem with my c# application, i have a class(settings) in which i store the design settings for my application:
settings class:

```
public class settings
{
    public string menuBackground, textColor, overallBackground, backgroundImage;
}
```

i have stored the settings inside an XML file:

```
<settings>
    <menuBackground>Black</menuBackground>
    <textColor>SteelBlue</textColor>
    <overallBackground>White</overallBackground>
    <backgroundImage>none</backgroundImage>
</settings>
```

but now the problem is that i need to change the colors of the form items in my application.

i managed to make the object form the xml file so thats not the problem, i have tried this:

```
var path = @"c:\test\test.xml";

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
{
    XmlSerializer xSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(settings));
    settings setting = (settings) xSer.Deserialize(fs);
    menuStrip1.BackColor = Color.setting.background;
    menuStrip1.ForeColor = setting.foreground;
}
```

but visual studio tell sme that the Color expects an identifier, so now my question is: how can i get the color inside my setting.background after the Color, so in this case for example it would be: Color.black;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned what UI framework you're using. If it's something that uses colors from System.Drawing, then you need to do `Color.FromName(setting.background)`

Comment: @MethodMan i couldnt before had to wait

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enum.Parse` to parse a `string` to an enum type:

```
 menuStrip1.BackColor = (Color)Enum.Parse(typeof(Color), setting.background);
```